# How can I check if 'use' of podsecuritypolicy is authorized in the namespace using 'kubectl auth can-i ... psp'?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, podsecuritypolicy

The following error is returned:

```
error: you must specify two or three arguments: verb, resource, and optional resourceName
```

when I executed:

```
kubectl auth --as=system:serviceaccount:mytest1:default can-i use psp 00-mytest1
```

I already have following manifests for `podsecuritypolicy` (psp.yaml), `role` (role.yaml) and `rolebinding` (rb.yaml) and deployed in the namespace `mytest1`.

psp.yaml

```
    apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
    kind: PodSecurityPolicy
    metadata:
      name: 00-mytest1
      labels: {}
      annotations:
        seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/allowedProfileNames: 'runtime/default'
        seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/defaultProfileName:  'runtime/default'
    spec:
      privileged: false
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
      requiredDropCapabilities:
      - ALL
      runAsUser:
        rule: 'MustRunAsNonRoot'
      runAsGroup:
        rule: 'MustRunAs'
        ranges:
        - min: 1000 
          max: 1000
        - min: 1
          max: 65535
      supplementalGroups:
        rule: 'MayRunAs'
        ranges:
        - min: 1
          max: 65535
      fsGroup:
        rule: 'MayRunAs'
        ranges:
        - min: 1
          max: 65535
      seLinux:
        rule: 'RunAsAny'
      hostNetwork: false
      hostIPC: false
      hostPID: false
      hostPorts: []
      volumes:
      - configMap
      - downwardAPI
      - emptyDir
      - projected
      - secret
```

role.yaml

```
    apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Role
    metadata:
      name: mytest1
      namespace: "mytest1"
      labels: {}
    rules:
    - apiGroups: ['policy']
      resources: ['podsecuritypolicies']
      verbs:     ['use']
      resourceNames: ['00-mytest1']
```

and rb.yaml

```
    apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    kind: RoleBinding
    metadata:
      name: mytest1
      namespace: "mytest1"
      labels: {}
    roleRef:
      apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
      kind: Role
      name: mytest1
    subjects:
    - kind: ServiceAccount
      name: default
      namespace: "mytest1"
```

I expect the return `yes` or `no` for `kubectl auth can-i ...` check and not the above mentioned error. Is the use-case for auth check correct? I appreciate he correction.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? How did you deploy it? What exactly did you do before this error? Did you see [this topic](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/884)?

Comment: Kubernetes version is 
`$ kubectl version --short 
Client Version: v1.21.4 
Server Version: v1.18.20` 
I do not believe it is a misplacement of options as per [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/884). See - 
`$ kubectl auth --as=system:serviceaccount:mytest1:default can-i get secret        
no
`
I deployed those one by one using `kubectl create -f <file_path>`. Of course you need to create new namespace `mytest1` to deploy those resources from manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the flag `--subresource`. If I execute

```
kubectl auth --as=system:serviceaccount:mytest1:default can-i use psp --subresource=00-mytest1
```

I have clear answer. In my situation:

```
no
```

You can also get an warning like this:

```
Warning: resource 'podsecuritypolicies' is not namespace scoped in group 'policy'
```

But it is related directly to your config.

For more information about kubectl auth can-i command check

```
kubectl auth can-i --help
```

in your terminal.
You can also read [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/).

Comment: Although I have those resources deployed on cluster, the command returns `no`. I do not understand, IMO it should have returned `yes`.

Comment: @jack_t, This is a topic for a separate question. You can [ask one question per topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post). The problem was related to incorrect arguments and if it has been resolved, please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you have problem with `yes` or `no` you should ask a new question.

Answer (score -1):

This one **doesnt** work:

```
kubectl auth can-i create deployments --namespace dev
```

However this **one works when "resource" name is provided** as shown below:

```
kubectl auth can-i get pods/dark-blue-app -n blue
```

Make sure to include `resource name / name-of-the-physical resource`